# CSS/Xpath selector for an element with a certain class containing an element with certain text

Tags: python, css, xpath, scrapy

In the Scrapy shell for http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/airbnb-inc/airbnb/, I'm trying to extract the links corresponding to the various releases of the AirBnB app:

[image]

As seen using Chrome's Inspect, the structure of this element is:

[image]

The children of the `listWidget` with class `appRow` contain links that I would like to extract. So, I would like to first select "The element with class `listWidget` which contains an element containing the text 'All version'".

So far, I've come up with

```
In [4]: response.css('.listWidget').xpath('.//*[contains(text(), "All versions")]').extract()
Out[4]: [u'<div class="widgetHeader">All versions </div>']
```

However, this selector goes 'too far down': I would like select the `listWidget` containing this element, not the element itself. How might I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use below `XPath` expression:

```
.//div[div[text()="All versions "]]
```

This will match `div` *that contains* `div` with `text` `"All versions "`

Comment: This seems to do what I asked: in my Scrapy shell, if I try `response.xpath('.//div[div[text()="All versions "]]').extract()`, I get `[u'<div style="position: relative; display: inline-block;">\n<div class="widgetHeader">All versions </div>\n</div>']`, which is the `div` enclosing the `div` with the given text. (It does not contain the `appRow` divs, but this is because I asked the wrong question: I'm actually interested in the `div` two levels up).

Comment: If you want to match `appRow` you might need to try `.//div[div[text()="All versions "]]/following-sibling::div[@class="appRow"]`

Comment: Yes, I used that approach in the end, and used CSS selectors instead of Xpath selectors to select classes following Scrapy's recommended practice (https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#when-querying-by-class-consider-using-css). The final expression I used to get the three links is `response.xpath('.//*[*[contains(text(), "All versions")]]/following-sibling::*').css('.appRow').css('.downloadLink').xpath('.//@href').extract()`.

Answer (score 2):

There's a CSS version of [XPath's `contains()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains) in Scrapy (in fact, [it's in `cssselect`](https://cssselect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#supported-selectors)).

From the OP's comments [in @Andersson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43852282/):

> The final expression I used to get the three links is
>
> ```
>    response.xpath('.//*[*[contains(text(), "All versions")]]/following-sibling::*').css('.appRow').css('.dow‌​nloadLink').xpath('.‌​//@href').extract()
> ```

one can translate that to:

```
In [6]: response.css(''':contains("All versions") ~ .appRow
                            .downloadLink::attr(href)''').extract()
```

which outputs:

```
Out[6]: 
['/apk/airbnb-inc/airbnb/airbnb-17-14-release/',
 '/apk/airbnb-inc/airbnb/airbnb-17-12-release/',
 '/apk/airbnb-inc/airbnb/airbnb-17-11-release/']
```